# ElasticSearch indexing string as integer then getting back the integer value in search result

Tags: java, elasticsearch

A team I am working with has a lot of dirty data. Sometimes a field might be a string, sometimes an integer for a particular field in several related Mongo collections. When it's a string, we can always rely on it being a valid integer, so these two work just fine:

```
PUT index/1
{
    "field": 1
}

PUT index/2
{
    "field": "2"
}
```

However, the _source field in the latter returns "field" as a string. Cleaning up the source data is not an option for me because it's outside of my authority. So is there a way to have ElasticSearch return "field" consistently as an integer or am I always going to be stuck with getting it back as whatever form it was indexed (integer or string)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using ES 5+, you can use an [ingest node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html), and an ingest pipeline which includes a [convert processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/convert-processor.html).

Comment: I couldn't find anything else, so I'm going to go with this.